# View my PHP source code in a browser via a button

Tags: php

I'm trying to view my php source code in the form of a button. I've tried implementing the `highlight_file()` function, but haven't had much luck. It keeps returning  "highlight_file(): Filename cannot be empty" or "failed opening". 
I'm super novice at PHP, but would really appreciate some guidance

```
<?php
    $file = $_GET["clientMain.php"];
    echo "<a class=\"btn btn-info btn-large\" role=\"button\"> Source Code for: " . $file . "</a>";
    highlight_file($file, TRUE);
?>
```

Comment: Maybe your `$file` variable must be just `$file = "clientMain.php";` ? Why you are using $_GET ?

Comment: I am not 100% sure but I think  `highlight_file() ` take the filename. so in your case `highlight_file('clientMain.php') `

Comment: The `$_GET` global contains input from the query string. It doesn't take information from the filesystem. You are thinking of something along the lines of `fopen()`

Comment: Please not that passing user input to `highlight_file` is a huge security risk

Comment: Thank-you all so much for the advice! I've managed to get the code to show - but I would like it to automatically open a new browser? Would this be as simple as setting a header location?

Comment: @SamanthaKounis that's a different question. Please create a new one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many problems with this code. Let me provide a solution, and then explain the issues and some words of caution.

```
1   <?php
2   
3       $requested_file = $_GET["requested_file"];
4   
5       if ($requested_file == "1") {
6           $filepath == "/path/to/file/mainClient.php"
7       } elseif ($requested_file == "2") {
8           $filepath == "/path/to/file/secondaryClient.php"
9       } 
10      
11      if (isset($filepath)) {
12          $output = highlight_file($filepath, TRUE);
13      }
14    
15   ?>
16  
17   <a href="http://example.com/?requested_file=1" class="btn" >View source for 'Main Client' file</a>
18   <a href="http://example.com/?requested_file=2" class="btn" >View source for 'Secondary Client' file</a>
```

**PROBLEM #1: THE BUTTON**

Your anchor tag is lacking an href, so it doesn't do anything.  You see on line 17 that I added an href that will send a request to the server to fetch this page: `example.com/`. Notice the `?requested_file=1` key/value pair in the URL? This is how the $_GET array is populated. The "key" is `requested_file` and the "value" is `1`

I added a second button on line 18 for illustrative purposes.

**PROBLEM #2: $_GET AND SECURITY**

In your example, you were trying to load the file name/path through the $_GET superglobal. This is extremely dangerous. Further, it doesn't appear that you fully understand how $_GET works - the parameter 'mainClient.php' inside `$_GET['mainClient.php'] identifies the "key" and not the "value". The value is sent by the user through the URL.

The $_GET superglobal is used for retrieving user-generated input from the URL string, in the form of a key/value pair. Because the user has full access to edit the URL sent to the server (and because it is visible), it presents significant security vulnerabilities if not used carefully.

Consider the case where the user types in the URL `http://example.com/?mainClient.php=db-config.php`. In this case, your code will fire and the file `all-my-secrets.php` will be revealed in all it's glory. That could be a very bad day for you.

In general it is very dangerous to use $_GET for anything other than signaling user actions from a list of pre-defined options. Allowing users to pass unsanitized data directly to your application is fraught with all kinds of risks, such as SQL-Injection, XSS attacks and more. Typically, $_GET is used safely for things like navigation, search terms, pre-defined actions, etc.

In my solution, I compare the $_GET request against a list of pre-defined numeric values (lines 5-9). If the `$_GET['requested_file']` key has a value that matches one of my pre-defined numeric choices, then and only then can the file's content sent back to the browser. So, no matter what the user sends in the URL, they can't get anything other than the two files I have pre-determined to be safe to share.  Notice also that the user doesn't have any clue what my file path looks like and I don't even have to reveal the file's name if I don't want to. Revealing that kind of information exposes me even more.

**PROBLEM #3: EMPTY VARIABLES**

The error `"highlight_file(): Filename cannot be empty"` is because your $file variable was empty when the URL did not specify a key/value pair for $_GET.

I have used the php `isset()` function on line 11 to prevent the call to `highlight_file()` if $filepath doesn't have anything assigned to it.

FYI - You were also having problems with your button text since it uses the same $file variable assigned by $_GET. This is unnecessary, so I hard coded the text I wanted to use with my button.

Comment: Thank-you so much for your response! This really clarifies what the problem was exactly and why the solution works. Really appreciate the effort put into the answer, thank-you!

Answer (score 0):

As Asenar says below, this is **not something you want to expose to a public webpage**, but if it's a local developer sandbox then you might use the following code:

```
<?php
$url = "http://localhost".$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
$file = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'];
echo "<a href='$url'> Source Code for: " . $url . "</a>";
echo "<HR>File: $file:<BR>";
highlight($file,FALSE);
// or echo highlight_file($file, TRUE); 
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, I have to say it's a really bad practice to allow to see code of any php file, this might be a serious security issue. So you might want to only allow a list of file.

You must provide the right path of your file, try to add the relative or absolute path to it.